# Programmatically, how can I tell on LINUX that the system is rebooting?

Tags: linux, reboot, system-shutdown, graceful-shutdown, runlevel

There is a lot about the "procedure" LINUX undertakes when a reboot or 'imminent shutdown' is underway. I wish to understand, programmatically, and react to, that a **REBOOT IS IMMINIENT.**

My application gets sent **TERM** and **HUP** signals which is all good and understood.
How can I tell the difference between a signal for immediate REBOOT reasons or just from another user?

**CONTEXT:**

If the system **is 100% rebooting** then my application will **SAVE** IT's STATE for **LOAD** on BOOT.

If however, a user, even "root" arbitrately kills my application then I **DO NOT** WISH to save the STATE.

I am using RedHat if it makes a difference.

I have attempted to research this quite extensively but so far I have not got the solution.
So you know... calling **STACK OVERFLOW**!

Thank you in-advance.

Comment: Which version of Red Hat Linux are you using?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9

Comment: For interest, I have a solution where my application analyzes the number of running processes and as the o/s typically takes 2 minutes before it "kill -9" everything so I monitor the running processes and understand from that but this is very random and not overall acceptable.

Comment: Why are you trying to differentiate between "stopping because the system is rebooting" and "stopping because someone decided to restart your application"? Wouldn't you want to save state in either case?

Comment: OMG! larsks. you legend and although it doesn't make any difference to the actual question/answer but regardless ofc I will tell you as it's you.

Comment: Possibly you could check for `systemctl is-active reboot.target shutdown.target`, but I haven't tested this.

Comment: Scenario: 
Security application with manually inputted session keys held in memory with encrypted one-time sessions to prevent dumping but you want to survive between genuine reboots so as to NOT enter the manual keys again.  Imagine, server is "root hacked" and therefore you do not wish to SAVE STATE with a simple kill... but with a genuine reboot then you do... and a reboot will be noticed where otherwise a quick KILL and restart and examine STATE may not... this is it is a quick overview nutshell.

Comment: I have tried systemctl as you mention and it did not work but I will re-attempt just to be sure my cmd line was correct however I have looked at this.

Comment: @larsks To confirm,  `systemctl is-active reboot.target shutdown.target`.
Reports "inactive" during a reboot.

Comment: Bummer. I am out of ideas!

Comment: Fair play... this is more of a LINUX KERNEL thing than a operating system level question I guess. So far, on over 30 systems... I need to check that the number of PIDS is reduced by * 0.95 to understand if a REBOOT is happening.  
**MUST BE A BETTER WAY SOMEONE PLEASE!**

Comment: The Linux kernel isn't able to answer this question for your process, because the init system (such as systemd) doesn't notify the Linux kernel about the reboot until the very end, when it's too late to write to the checkpoint files. So you should ask for this info from your init system.

Comment: Don't. You cannot distinguish a genuine reboot from a hacked reboot.

Answer (score 0):

```
/run/systemd/shutdown/scheduled
```

This will is created if the system is using systemd.

```
USEC=1677685364145817
WARN_WALL=1
MODE=reboot
```

Comment: Are you saying the scheduled fie is created when reboot starts? Or, it should be created to generate the "wall" "message?

Comment: It is generated at reboot and with a pending shutdown.  So if you receive a SIGTERM  you can check this file prior to quitting to do "stuff" if needed.

Comment: However in the end as well as checking for this file.... I actually monitor any PID with a PPID of 1 and then before QUITTING I check if at least 50% of the monitored PID's have quit and then I decide it is a reboot.

Comment: (any improved logic gratefully received)